# Does she do her homework?

Tags: do-support

> She **does** her homework.
>
> Does she **do** her homework?

Why the questioning sentence is using "do"?

Answer (score 3):

> **Does** she **do** her homework?

To ask a question, we need to use an [auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) at the beginning of the sentence. In our case, the auxiliary verb is **do**: this is called **[do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)**.

But since "she" is a singular third-person pronoun, we turn **do** into **does**. The first **do** carries the third-person ending **s**(or **es**) instead of the second. So there's no reason to leave the second verb with the same ending.

Compare:

> She **flew** home. ("Flew" is the Past Tense form of "fly")
>   **Did** she **fly** home?

Notice how the auxiliary verb **do** assumed the Past Tense form **did**, and the *main verb* **fly** now has no need to be in the Past Tense form: the auxiliary verb does this work.

The main verb contains the meaning, the auxiliary verb is a "helping verb".

In your example sentence, the first **do** (in the form **does**) is an *auxiliary verb*, and the second **do** (in the form **do**) is a *[main verb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/main-verb)*.

Comment: Very nicely did (American regionalism)

Answer (score 2):

#### The usual situation

When turning a statement into a question, we move the first word of the verb to the beginning of the sentence:

> Statement: She ***is*** doing her homework.
>   Question: ***Is*** she *doing* her homework?

#### An exception

If there is only one word in the verb, we use a form of *to do* to add a word to the verb, then move the added *do*:

> Statement:  She *does* her homework.
>   Two-word verb:  She ***does*** do her homework.
>   Question:  ***Does*** she *do* her homework?

> Statement:  She *has* a question.
>   Two-word verb:  She ***does*** have a question.
>   Question:  ***Does*** she *have* a question?

#### An exception to the exception

If the verb is a one-word form of *to be*, we can't use *to do* to add a word.  All we can do is move the verb that exists.

> Statement:  She *is* a student .
>   Mistake:  She <strike>does</strike> *is* a student.
>   Question:  ***Is*** she a student?