# Third person singular 's' in question formation

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, do-support

A co-worker of mine took an ELL test for her job and she had to compose a question.
She wrote:

> "Does she play**s**?"

I know that in a statement rather than a question, the third person singular subject is in effect necessitating the 's' on the end of play.

But what is the rule in questions that makes the 's' not needed? I don't know how to explain why we don't do this in a question.

Comment: See also [Auxilliary “do” with the subject in questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/auxilliary-do-with-the-subject-in-questions); and [When can we omit “does” in the question sentence](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23489/when-can-we-omit-does-in-the-question-sentence); and [How do I use the auxiliary “do” in questions?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31431/how-do-i-use-the-auxiliary-do-in-questions); and [Does she do her homework?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40774/does-she-do-her-homework); and

Answer (score 4):

Typically, only the first verb in each clause can be **finite**:

> I **play**.
>   I **played**.
>   She **plays**.
>   She **played**.

As you can see, this verb changes form.  It shows tense (present or past) and agrees with the subject (adding ***-s*** if the subject is third person singular present).  This must be our **finite verb**.

Our example is a declarative clause.  To make it into a question, we should turn it into an interrogative clause.  And for this sort of sentence, we do that by swapping the subject and auxiliary verb, like this:

> *She* **was** safe.　　→　　**Was** *she* safe?

This is called **Subject-Auxiliary Inversion** (SAI).  We use SAI to mark these sentences as questions.  And in this case, SAI is possible because we have the auxiliary ***be***.

But what if our example doesn't have an auxiliary verb?  Let's look at our example from earlier:

> I **play**.
>   I **played**.
>   She **play*s***.
>   She **play*ed***.

We can't swap the subject and auxiliary verb if we don't have one!  Let's solve that problem by adding the meaningless ("dummy") auxiliary ***do***:

> I **do** play.
>   I **did** play.
>   She **does** play.
>   She **did** play.

Now we've got two verbs!  And only the first can be **finite**.  In this case, that means ***do***!  And as you can see, ***do*** now changes form, but ***play*** doesn't!  That's because ***play*** is no longer **finite**.

Now we can make it into a question.  So, let's do **Subject-Auxiliary Inversion** again, moving the auxiliary before the subject ***I***:

> **Do** I play?
>   **Did** I play?
>   **Does** she play?
>   **Did** she play?

These questions are formed correctly.  But what about your example?

> ***Does** she **plays?**

It doesn't work!  Why not?  Because we'd have two **finite** verbs.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks a sentence as ungrammatical, and **bold** in examples marks a verb as **finite**.

Answer (score 2):

Because the "adjusting to the subject" is done in two ways:

1. *Without* auxillary verb (aka open-ended questions):
   Adjust the main verb.

   > He play**s** the piano. <-> Who play**s** the piano?
2. *With* auxillary verb (aka yes-no questions or closed-ended questions):
   Adjust the auxillary verb, the main verb stays in the infinitive.

   > He play**s** the piano. <-> **Does** he play the piano?

Note that native speakers tend to "forget" that irregular verbs - and auxillary verbs are irregular - switch their forms instead of adding the 's'. So yes, there is an adjustment, but not via the '+s'.

---

Edit for the sake of completeness:
as @pazzo noted, there is the unchanged "He plays the piano?" question as well - same rules apply: No auxillary -> adjust main verb.

Comment: Also: *He play**s** the piano?*, a common word order for questions (unchanged from non-question form. Distinguishable by the tone of the speaker). But I can't help thinking that this question is a duplicate of a previous question.

Comment: @pazzo: true. But not what I would suggest for a learner - can only be recognized in spoken language by intonation. (or the '?' obviously for written tests)

Comment: As you like, but I teach ESL, and we teach this from rather early on, as it is similar to other languages, and also as a way of showing the importance of tone in English...

Comment: @pazzo - and I have worked with international collegues (english as 3rd language and a h**l of an accent...) who obviously never got the memo on the importance of intonation. Add to this a crackling phone line and you have a recipe for disaster. Will add this type for the sake of completeness. Did you find the duplicate?

Comment: @Araucaria Because it has an auxillary -> adjust the auxillary. Wil try to phrase it better later, am on the run.

Comment: @Stephie Maybe I misunderstood. Sorry. Have remove my DV, but might benefit from a slight reword :)